# Gateway Extension Error

Tags: expresso-store, ee2, extension

I installed a new custom gateway I use via omnipay into EE2 backend, but when I go to 'Expresso Store' and click on 'Payment Gateways' to see if my payment gateway displays in the list, it gives me the following error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Omnipay\Common\Exception\RuntimeException' with message 'Class '\Omnipay\PayU\Gateway' not found' in C:\wamp\www\flook\trunk\backend\expressionengine\third_party\store\vendor\omnipay\common\src\Omnipay\Common\GatewayFactory.php
```

What could the problem be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I misspelt Omnipay (Onmipay) in my extension. Watch your spelling guys! Stupid mistake by me!

Answer (score 3):

You need to tell Store about your new gateway in the ext. file. Use the `store_payment_gateways` hook and pass in the $gateways array:

```
public function store_payment_gateways($gateways)
```

Then ensure that you add your gateway to the list:

```
$gateways[] = 'PayU';
```

Include the autoloader:

```
$composer = require(PATH_THIRD.'store/autoload.php');
```

And tell Composer where to find your gateway:

```
$composer->add('Omnipay', __DIR__);
```

Putting it all together it should look something like this as a single method:

```
public function store_payment_gateways($gateways)
{
    // Language file?
    ee()->lang->loadfile('store_payu');

    // Add the new gateway to Store's known list
    $gateways[] = 'PayU';

    // Tell Store where to find the class files
    $composer = require(PATH_THIRD.'store/autoload.php');
    $composer->add('Omnipay', __DIR__);

    return $gateways;
}
```

Comment: Oh my goodness - I misspelt Omnipay - I had it as Onmipay. OOOPS. This is why programming is so much fun....

Comment: Ha, yeah those typos can take away hours of your life that you'll never get back. Glad you got it figured out.